# Trying to Understand Why .attr('value', 'foo') Works But .val('foo') Doesn't

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I thought I understood the whole prop vs. attr thing, but I just ran in to a case that made me question that understanding.

I was writing a test for a Backbone View which generates a table, and my test essentially did the following:

```
// assert that $table.find('input[value="foo"]').length == 2
$table.find('input[value="foo"]:first').val('bar');
// assert that $table.find('input[value="foo"]').length == 1
```

The strange part is, that second assertion failed.  After a lot of head-banging-against-the-wall time I finally tried:

```
// assert that $table.find('input[value="foo"]').length == 2
$table.find('input[value="foo"]:first').attr('value', 'bar');
// assert that $table.find('input[value="foo"]').length == 1
```

Lo and behold, my test passed.

Now, I wish I could post a fiddle with all the relevant code, but there's just way too much (the table View alone is 685 lines), but I'm looking for a general understanding type answer, not a specific "fix X in your code".  And what I'm trying to understand is, why would there ever be a case where:

```
$table.find('input[value="foo"]:first').val('bar');
```

does nothing at all, while:

```
$table.find('input[value="foo"]:first').attr('value', 'bar');
```

works as expected?

P.S. I shouldn't say the `.val('bar')` did nothing at all; if I did a `.val()` afterwards it would show that the value had changed ... but if I checked the actual element, or used a new selector, or anything like that it became apparent that `val` hadn't really changed anything.  This only confuses me further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple example should shine some light on things. Suppose we start with this HTML:

```
<input id="t1">
<input id="t2">
```

and then we execute this JavaScript:

```
$('#t1').val('pancakes');
$('#t2').attr('value', 'pancakes');
```

Visually, both `<input>`s will look they same, they'll both say `pancakes`. But, if you look at the underlying DOM elements, you'll see:

```
<input id="t1">
<input id="t2" value="pancakes">
```

So using [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) more or less simulates you fiddling with the form elements using the mouse and keyboard; none of this will change the underlying element. Calling [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2), however, will change the underlying element and `#t2` will end up with a real full blown `value` attribute (see [adeneo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15513598/479863) if you want to know why).

Why is the difference important? I notice that you're using attribute selectors so a quick look at this is worthwhile:

```
$('input[value=pancakes]').length
```

That will be `1` because only one of the `<input>`s even has a `value` attribute let alone a `value` with the value we're looking for.

The problem isn't that:

```
$table.find('input[value="foo"]:first').val('bar');
```

doesn't do anything, the problem is that it doesn't do anything that an attribute selector can see because [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) doesn't do anything to attributes at all.

---

Simple demo of the above, open your console and see interesting things: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/PNtKk/

Answer (score 3):

`val()` changes the property directly, and it does'nt show in the console, while `attr()` changes the attribute with the native `setAttribute()` so that shows in the console.

`val()` would be the proper method to set an elements value.